# Computer restarts itself everyday with a short notice and no postpone option (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, reboot

Between 4pm and 5pm everyday, my Windows 7 desktop computer restarts itself after the warnings below.

It's an enterprise company. IT Team tried a few things but none of them worked so far. They are suggesting re-imaging the computer. Is there anything else I can do to fix this issue without re-image?

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE (2/13/2018)**

Solved the issue by:

- Logging in with administrator account
- Repairing SEP (Symantec Endpoint Protection)

Comment: What we need to determine is where this restart is being triggered from. Is it a pending file rename? A Windows Update-triggered event? An SCCM-triggered event? Or something else. There are several places Windows stores and checks for restart needs, and from these you can deduce where the trigger is initiating.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a local or Enterprise GPO that is running on your PC. Look in windows updates: Start, Control panel, windows updates, and see if it says: 
windows update is controlled by your system administrator

This means that windows updates are controlled by the Active Directory GPO.

Other wise, look at windows updates scheduled as an administrator to the local PC and see if there is a local GPO or setting with in windows updates to run, update, and reboot. There is no need to run updates every day. I would suggest every Wednesday, or over the weekend.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Run 'gpresult.exe /h result.html' in cmd to see the list of all GPOs that are being applied.  Your PC may have a problem picking up GP changes - I've seen that, and was only I was able to fix was with a reimage.

Comment: The message that updates are managed by the organization is famously NOT a certain evidence of that fact, but this is still a reasonable thing to assume, because the computer IS an enterprise system. Frankly, as an IT professional, the time it would take to diagnose and repair the system manually is likely much longer than the time it would take to re-image the computer, and so that's what I would recommend as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check Windows Update history - most probably it is cycling because
some update fails to install, then is detected again the next day
and is reinstalled.

The Event Viewer might also contain helpful information.